# I'm not sure what 言われちゃえ means

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

The sentence is 「なにこれ可愛い！」って言われちゃえ. I get the なにこれ可愛い part, but I'm not sure what 言われちゃえ means. It seems to be in the passive/imperative form?

For context, here's where I found the sentence:

https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2135017506780585501

Answer (score 3):

> 「なにこれ可愛{かわい}い！」って言われちゃえ。

「言{い}われちゃえ」 is the colloquial way of saying 「言われてしまえ」, which is in the "***passive imperative***" form.

The only problem is, though, that the sentence is very difficult to translate usng the same passive imperative construct. The literal translation would look something like:

"Be told 'What is this?  It's so freaking cute!'", but that is clumsy at best.

To include the rather ***light and jocular*** feeling of the original, I might go with something like:

"You sure will have people say 'That's freaking cute!' "

Comment: Isn't it passive imperative rather than causative?

Comment: If this title were on an American recipe site, and assuming the page is targeted towards readers who are familiar with what 'kawaii' means, I would imagine it saying something like: "Make 'em say 'Kawaii!'"